# differentiable as an R2 function v.s. as a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be a complex function. Denote its real and imaginary part by $u: \mathbb C \to \mathbb R$ and $v: \mathbb C \to \mathbb R$ respectively.
Consider the function $\widetilde f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $\widetilde f (x,y) = (u(x+iy),v(x+iy))$.
I am aware that $f$ is differentiable (in the complex sense, i.e. $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$ exists) iff $\widetilde f$ is continuously differentiable and $u$ and $v$ satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equation.
I think if "continuously differentiable" above is replaced by "differentiable (in the real sense, i.e. $\lim_{\mathbf h \to 0} \frac{\lvert \widetilde f(\mathbf x+ \mathbf h)-\widetilde f(\mathbf x) - D \widetilde f \mathbf h\rvert}{\lvert \mathbf h \rvert} = 0$)", the "if" part will not hold.
Can anyone give a counterexample for this? (Or if it holds, can anyone give a proof?)

Comment: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2321164 indicates, for example, the Looman-Menchoff theorem requires only that (a) the partial derivatives $u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y$ exist on a neighborhood (b) they solve CR in a neighborhood (c) they are real differentiable on a neighborhood (d) $u+iv$ is continuous. // The pointwise result does not require continuous differentiability; this is also mentioned in the above-linked article.

Comment: @Alex: your definition of "differentiable in the real sense" has a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort this thing one point in the domain at a time.

Fact:

$f\colon U \to \mathbb{C}$ is complex differentiable at $z$

if and only if

$f$ is differentiable at $z$ ( as a function from $U$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ ) and 
the partial derivatives at $z$ ( which exist since $f$ is differentiable at $z$) satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Note that differentiable at $z$ implies continuous at $z$.

Therefore:

$f\colon U \to \mathbb{C}$ is complex differentiable on  $U$

if and only if

$f$ is differentiable on $U$ ( as a function from $U$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ ) and 
the partial derivatives  ( which exist since $f$ is differentiable on $U$) satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

The first equivalence is elementary and the second follows from the first and definitions.

From the theory of complex functions it follows that a function $f$  is complex differentiable at $U$ if and only if it is complex analytic, that is for every point $z_0$ in $U$ the values of $f$ on an open  disk centered at  $z_0$ and contained in $U$ are given by a power series in $(z-z_0)$.